# using replace with browser prefixes js/css

Tags: javascript, css, replace, vendor-prefix

I am making a javascript script that wants to do something like this:

```
elementObject.style.transform.replace('...','...');
elementObject.style.webkitTransform.replace('...','...');
```

And just to clear this up, yes, I have set both of those styles earlier in the script. However, this causes errors because in Chrome, for example, it does not recognize the transform style. Therefore, replace fails because `elementObject.style.transform` is undefined, and undefined has no method replace. Is there any way to do this without causing these errors? I just want the `webkit` transform, i do not need `moz`, `o`, or any other prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var st = elementObject.style;
if (st.transform !== undefined) st.transform = st.transform.replace('...','...');
// ...
```

or more general:

```
function replaceStyle(element, style, text, replacement) {
  var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz', 'o', 'ms'];
  var st = element.style;
  if (st[style] !== undefined) st[style] = st[style].replace(text, replacement);
  style = style.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+style.substring(1);
  for (var i=0, l=vendors.length; i<l; i++) {
    var vendorStyle = vendors[i]+style;
    if (st[vendorStyle] !== undefined)
      st[vendorStyle] = st[vendorStyle].replace(text, replacement);
  }
}

// sample call (setting width from "40px" to "100%")
replaceStyle( myElementObject, 'with', '40px', '100%' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) design pattern.

For example:

```
function transformStyle() {
    var tempEl = document.createElement('div'),
        elStyle = tempEl.style;

    if (typeof elStyle.transform !== 'undefined') {
        transformStyle = function (el, val) {
            val != null && (el.style.transform = val);
            return el.style.transform;
        };
    } else if (typeof elStyle.webkitTransform !== 'undefined') {
        transformStyle = function (el, val) {
            val != null && (el.style.webkitTransform = val);
            return el.style.webkitTransform;
        };
    } else {
        transformStyle = function () { return ''; }; //ignore when not supported
    }

    tempEl = null;
    elStyle = null;

    return transformStyle.apply(this, arguments);
}

var el = document.createElement('div');

transformStyle(el, 'rotate(-2deg)'); //set style
transformStyle(el); //rotate(-2deg)
```

Obviously you could write something more generic such as a `style` method that allows accessing or modifying any styles. You could use a list of vendor prefixes to make the code more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as well. The previous code was just an example.